# Attach Records to Chat Transcripts option missing

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console, livechattranscript

I enabled Live Agent in my developer edition org and the attach tool is missing in Live agent chat.

As per the [Salesforce article](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_live_agent_attach_records_to_transcript.htm), I should see the below option in live chat

[image]

but I don't see that icon in my org and it shows as like this:

[image]

I logged in as System Admin and have access on everything. Screenshot for reference:

[image]

Any help on this?

**NOTE**: I am using omni channel routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIEQu.png) indirectly says that attachment tool(that I was expecting to see) is only for Live Agent routing and not for omni routing .

I wanted to double confirm this so I disabled omni routing and I can see the attachment tool.

[image]

Once I enabled, omni routing, the attachment tool is missing and now I see a sidebar lookup component as in the below screenshot.

[image]

I wish it was clearly mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

To initiate file transfer for Agents, you have to enable **Agent File Transfer Enabled** in Live Agent Configurations.

[image]

*Please Note that: - A customer can’t upload a file until you initiate the file transfer by clicking the file transfer icon. This helps prevent customers from uploading unsolicited or potentially dangerous files into the chat.*

Comment: Tried but still don't see the attach option.

Comment: Have you tried in different browsers?

Comment: After I enabled the above setting as you mentioned, I am seeing the Attach file option but Attach records option is still missing. Here is the screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/JaRGn

Comment: The article I mentioned in the question is from Spring'14 release and this may apply only to old orgs. My developer edition org is pretty new(created two montsh ago), aslo I am seeing other options to attach records but not the same UI as in the article. Thanks for your time in looking into this.

Comment: But I can see the same UI in one of my developer Org created in May.

Comment: Then I am not sure, what is missing in my org. I can forward credentials for my developer org, if you want :)

Comment: Hi, Just wanted to add this information that I am using omni channel routing. Are you using omni channel in your developer edition org aswell? Thanks